# Add diferent condition into where clause depending on case condition

Tags: sql, sql-server

If column `A` is not empty I should add one condition and if it is empty, then I should add another condition. Something like this:

```
select *
from table t
where case when len(t.A) > 0 then t.A = (select B from anothertable ) 
      else t.C = (select D from anothertable)
```

As this does not compiles, and I can't use `IF` clause within `WHERE` is there any other way to achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can rephrase the login in the `WHERE` clause to make it work:

```
SELECT *
FROM table_t
WHERE
    (LEN(t.A) > 0   AND t.A IN (SELECT B FROM anothertable) ) OR
    (LEN(t.A) <= 0) AND t.C IN (SELECT D FROM anothertable) );
```

To address the comment by @HoneyBadger if the subqueries on `anothertable` return more than one record, then this query would error out if we used `t.A = (subquery)`.  If you intend to use equals, then you would have to ensure that the subquery only returns a single record.  Your suggestion to use `WHERE IN` might fix the problem.

Comment: Well, I guess that's what I was looking for. Thank you mate!

Comment: Yea, I'm actually going to use `t.A IN (SELECT B FROM anothertable)...`. Thanks